# How to strip HDR metadata from mkv video, without re-encoding?

Tags: video, matroska, hdr

I have a video file in a mkv container. This video file is 4K/BT2020/SDR but with an extra HDR layer that is useless because the video is SDR: the "correct" colors are already baked-in. The HDR layer makes the result overly saturated and crushed. I have verified this by playing the video through the X11 video output in MPV, which doesn't support HDR and ignores the metadata layer, and the video looked perfect (color, saturation, contrast, brightness... all good). It isn't a proper solution for me as X11 performs very poorly on my machine and results in frequent screen tearing.

Is there a way I can strip the HDR-metadata layer from this video file, preferably without re-encoding ?

Environment: Linux

mediainfo:

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L5@Main
HDR format                               : SMPTE ST 2094 App 4, Version 1, HDR10+ Profile B compatible
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Duration                                 : 58 min 3 s
Bit rate                                 : 14.8 Mb/s
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 2 160 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.074
Stream size                              : 6.00 GiB (96%)
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.2020
Transfer characteristics                 : PQ
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.2020 non-constant
Mastering display color primaries        : Display P3
Mastering display luminance              : min: 0.0020 cd/m2, max: 1000 cd/m2
Maximum Content Light Level              : 133 cd/m2
Maximum Frame-Average Light Level        : 501 cd/m2
```

Comment: Have you checked what separate streams are available on MKV level? e.g. via `mkvinfo`?

Comment: @Robert I've added the mediainfo output. There's only one video track and it has HDR10+ metadata.